# Customiser `active_callback` not working on control with `postMessage` transport method

Tags: theme-customizer

I have 4x custom settings within 2x custom sections, with the second setting in each section relying on an `active_callback` to show/hide it.

In both cases the `active_callback` checks the value of the first custom setting from that section, and it was working perfectly until I started using `transport => postMessage` for the first setting (all settings below, as it's easier to show them than it is explain them).

There are no JS errors, so I assume it must be something to do with how the active callback is fired (I.e. perhaps it's not when `postMessage` is used).

While I can add some additional JS to cover my requirements, I'd be curious to know whether or not this is expected behavior, and if it is, whether or not there is a way to fix my problem.

Here are the settings (registered using the `customize_register` action hook)...

```
/**
 * Create the custom 'Archive Pages' section and register settings
 */
function register_settings_archive_template($wp_customise){

    $wp_customise->add_section('section_template_archive' , array(
        'title'             => __('Archive Pages', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'priority'          => 60
    ));

    /**
     * Link tile size (overrides General setting)
     */

    $wp_customise->add_setting('archive_link_tile_size', array(
        'default'   => 'default',
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customise->add_control('archive_link_tile_size', array(
        'label'         => __('Link tile size', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'section'       => 'section_template_archive',
        'type'          => 'radio',
        'choices'       => array(
            'default'   => __('Default', TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'large'     => __('Large', TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'small'     => __('Small', TEXT_DOMAIN)
        ),
        'description'   => __('The size of link tile that you wish to dsipay on archive pages.', TEXT_DOMAIN),
    ));

    /**
     * Show 'More...' link
     */

    $wp_customise->add_setting('archive_show_more_link', array(
        'default'   => false,
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customise->add_control('archive_show_more_link', array(
        'label'             => __('Show link to Link/Post', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'section'           => 'section_template_archive',
        'type'              => 'checkbox',
        'description'       => __('Whether or not to show the \'More...\' link underneath a large link tile on archive pages.  Note that links cannot be displayed in conjunction with \'Small\' Link Tiles.', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'active_callback'   => '_check_is_link_tile_size_large'
    ));

}

/**
 * Create the custom 'Search Results' section and register settings
 */
function register_settings_search_template($wp_customise){

    $wp_customise->add_section('section_template_search' , array(
        'title'             => __('Search Results', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'priority'          => 60
    ));

    /**
     * Link tile size (overrides General setting)
     */

    $wp_customise->add_setting('search_link_tile_size', array(
        'default'   => 'default',
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customise->add_control('search_link_tile_size', array(
        'label'         => __('Link tile size', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'section'       => 'section_template_search',
        'type'          => 'radio',
        'choices'       => array(
            'default'   => __('Default', TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'large'     => __('Large', TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'small'     => __('Small', TEXT_DOMAIN)
        ),
        'description'   => __('The size of link tile that you wish to dsipay on the search results page.', TEXT_DOMAIN)
    ));

    /**
     * Show 'More...' link
     */

    $wp_customise->add_setting('search_show_more_link', array(
        'default'   => false,
        'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ));

    $wp_customise->add_control('search_show_more_link', array(
        'label'             => __('Show link to Link/Post', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'section'           => 'section_template_search',
        'type'              => 'checkbox',
        'description'       => __('Whether or not to show the \'More...\' link underneath a large link tile on the search results page.  Note that links cannot be displayed in conjunction with \'Small\' Link Tiles.', TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'active_callback'   => '_check_is_link_tile_size_large'
    ));

}
```

And here is the active callback...

```
public function _check_is_link_tile_size_large($control){

    $control_id = $control->id;

    switch($control_id):

        case 'archive_show_more_link' :
            $validation_setting = 'archive_link_tile_size';
            break;

        case 'search_show_more_link' :
            $validation_setting = 'search_link_tile_size';
            break;

    endswitch;

    return ($control->manager->get_setting($validation_setting)->value() === 'large');

}
```

## Update

I should have added this in the first place, but here is the JS that I am using to update the above settings via `postMessage` -

```
(function($){

    var api = wp.customize;

    CustomiseArchivePages();    // Customise settings in the Archive Pages section
    CustomiseSearchResults();   // Customise settings in the Search Results section

    /**
     * Customise settings in the Archive Pages section
     */
    function CustomiseArchivePages(){

        /** Link Tile size */
        api('archive_link_tile_size', function(value){
            value.bind(function(newval){
                PreviewLinkTile(newval, api.get().archive_show_more_link);
            });
        });

        /** Show/hide 'More...' button  */
        api('archive_show_more_link', function(value){
            value.bind(function(newval){
                PreviewLinkTile(api.get().archive_link_tile_size, newval);
            }); 
        });

    }

    /**
     * Customise settings in the Search Results section
     */
    function CustomiseSearchResults(){

        /** Search box placeholder text */
        api('search_box_placeholder', function(value){
            value.bind(function(newval){
                $('input.s').attr('placeholder', newval);
            });
        });

        /** Link Tile size */
        api('search_link_tile_size', function(value){
            value.bind(function(newval){
                PreviewLinkTile(newval, api.get().search_show_more_link);
            });
        });

        /** Show/hide 'More...' button  */
        api('search_show_more_link', function(value){
            value.bind(function(newval){
                PreviewLinkTile(api.get().search_link_tile_size, newval);
            });
        });

    }

    /**
     * Set the link tile size and show/hide the 'More...' button on link tiles
     *
     * @param required string linkTileSize          The size of the link tiles that are being displayed
     * @param required string showMoreInfoButton    Whether or not to show the 'More...' button
     */
    function PreviewLinkTile(linkTileSize, showMoreInfoButton){

        var linksContainer = $('#links-container'),         // The links container
            linkTiles = $('.link-tile', linksContainer);    // Every individual link tile

        linkTileSize = (linkTileSize !== 'default') ? linkTileSize : api.get().general_link_tile_size;  // If the new size is default, grab the default size

        /**
         * Set the link tile size
         */
        switch(linkTileSize){

            case 'large' :

                /** Set the links container classes */
                linksContainer.removeClass('uk-grid-width-1-2 uk-grid-width-small-1-3 uk-grid-width-medium-1-4 uk-grid-width-large-1-5')
                    .addClass('uk-grid-width-1-1 uk-grid-width-small-1-1 uk-grid-width-medium-1-2 uk-grid-width-large-1-3');

                /** Set the link tile class */
                linkTiles.removeClass('link-tile-small')
                    .addClass('link-tile-large');

                break;

            case 'small' :

                /** Set the links container classes */
                linksContainer.removeClass('uk-grid-width-1-1 uk-grid-width-small-1-1 uk-grid-width-medium-1-2 uk-grid-width-large-1-3')
                    .addClass('uk-grid-width-1-2 uk-grid-width-small-1-3 uk-grid-width-medium-1-4 uk-grid-width-large-1-5');

                /** Set the link tile class */
                linkTiles.removeClass('link-tile-large')
                    .addClass('link-tile-small');

                break;

            default :
                console.log('An unexpected error occured when customising the Link Tile size: The new size could not be determined.');
                break;

        }

        /**
         * Show/hide the 'More...' button
         */
        if(showMoreInfoButton && linkTileSize === 'large'){
            linkTiles.addClass('show-more-button');
        } else {
            linkTiles.removeClass('show-more-button');
        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes, it is expected that if using `postMessage`, the `active_callback` wouldn't fire because it is only called when the preview refreshes. If you want to re-evaluate the `active_callback` handlers, you can refresh the preview via `wp.customize.previewer.refresh()`

Comment: Thanks, but if I `refresh` then it totally destroys the point of using `postMessage` in the first place. Plus `wp.customize.previewer.refresh()` generates an error...

Comment: Yes, good point. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `postMessage` uses JavaScript entirely, any PHP `active_callback` will not get called unless the preview refreshes (e.g. via `wp.customize.previewer.refresh()`). So what you need to do is implement the `active` callback in JavaScript instead, like so:

```
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function () {
    wp.customize.control( 'archive_show_more_link', function( control ) {
        var setting = wp.customize( 'archive_link_tile_size' );
        control.active.set( 'large' === setting.get() );
        setting.bind( function( value ) {
            control.active.set( 'large' === value );
        } );
    } );

    wp.customize.control( 'search_show_more_link', function( control ) {
        var setting = wp.customize( 'search_link_tile_size' );
        control.active.set( 'large' === setting.get() );
        setting.bind( function( value ) {
            control.active.set( 'large' === value );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Make sure that this script gets enqueued into the Customizer pane and *not* the Customizer preview. In other words, enqueue the JS at the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I'm getting an error - `wp.customize.control()` is not a function.  I also get the same error when using `wp.customize.previewer.refresh()`.  Note also that I've now updated my question to include the current JS that I am using.

Comment: You need to make sure your code is wrapped in `wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function () {} )`. The function called when `ready` will ensure that the `control` and `previewer` are defined.

Comment: The `ready` state is never achieved. The closest I can get is using `preview-ready`, but I'm still unable to access `previewer` and `control`. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see. So the problem is that you are enqueueing the script into the Customizer preview when you actually need to enqueue it into the Customizer pane. In other words, just enqueue at `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you - your code needs to be in a completely separate file.  It is working now, so thanks very much for the help.  I am seeing a random error in Firebug though - **TypeError: a is undefined: _...Case()},each:function(a,b,c){var d,e=0,f=a.length,g=r(a);if(c){if(g){for(;f>e;e+..._** - It doesn't seem to stop anything from working though.

Comment: Actually, there is one small problem... When the customiser loads and the active state of a control is set (`control.active.set( 'large' === setting.get() );`), even if it's set to `false` the control is still shown.  I'm checking this by adding `console.log(control.active.get());`, but it's not a major issue because I can just use my PHP `active_callback` for the initial preview load.

Comment: I've just written up a blog post about this, including an example for how you can eliminate having replicated logic between PHP and JS: https://make.xwp.co/2016/07/24/dependently-contextual-customizer-controls/

Comment: `wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function () {} )` never fires for me. Related http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238941/wp-customize-bind-ready-event-not-fired