# Theme Customizer - Hide / grey out settings based on other setting

Tags: theme-customizer

Using the Theme Customizer, is it possible to hide / grey out options based on other options?

For example, I have a button. There are 3 settings related to the button:

- Is it shown (checkbox)
- Text inside button
- Link location

If the button is not shown (i.e. unchecked), could the other 2 options be hidden / disabled in some way?

There is no point being able to customize something that is hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. What you are looking for is the control's  `active` state. This can be set in PHP via a control's `active_callback`.

For more details, see:
http://ottopress.com/2015/whats-new-with-the-customizer/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211953/8521