# wp.customize.bind ready event not fired

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I'm trying to add some javascript to my theme customizer. My JS file is loaded no problem and my document ready event works but `wp.customize.bind()` isn't calling my callback.

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
  console.log('binding')
  wp.customize.bind('ready', function(){
    console.log('ready')
  })
})
```

`binding` gets outputed to the console but `ready` does not.

What am I missing? there seems to be little to no documentation on using the javascript here.

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211779/customiser-active-callback-not-working-on-control-with-postmessage-transport

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Binding logs, ready not. That there is so little documentation available to the javascript API is really frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Do not put the Customizer `ready` event handler inside of the jQuery `event` handler. The Customizer `ready` will trigger at jQuery `ready`, so you are adding the event handler too late. Just do:

```
wp.customize.bind('ready', function(){
    console.log('ready');
});
```

Your JS needs to be enqueued with `customize-controls` script as its dependency. Enqueue at the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. 
The reason it was not binding for me was because I had this error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsync' of undefined"` on my console.

It was caused because I removed the `header_textcolor` settings from the theme template by using `$wp_customize->remove_setting( 'header_textcolor' );` but it was still being referenced in the js.

After fixing this, bind worked as intended.